# Variable inside the function is not available in jquery but available without the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new with javascript, but I'm really confused with a behavior of the function:

```
$('#get_file').on('click', function(event) {
    var start_date = $("#table_date_start").val(),
        end_date = $("#table_date_end").val(),
        href = apiUrl.concat(
                'download_pdf',
                '?start_date=' + start_date,
                '&end_date=' + end_date,
                '&order=', order[1],
                '&order_type=', order[0]
            );
    e.target.href = href;
});
```

variables start_date, end_date and href are not available inside the function, but available outside. How comes that? Could someone, please, give me a hint why is this happening?

Comment: are your variables global? if not, make it global

Comment: What makes you think that the variables *are not available inside the function*?

Comment: its good practices declare variables in new line

Comment: @Adelin, they does not showing in the href request and the console.log is empty as well.

Comment: What browser are you using?  This seems to be a browser specific problem as it works fine in Chrome, but not in IEdge: https://jsfiddle.net/5j7kro38/1/

Comment: *"why are they available outside"* - you'll need to provide more code - it could be you have these defined elsewhere as well.

Comment: @Freedomn-m, Thanks. I'm using Vivaldi, so yeah, it might be a browser problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring all 3 vars in the same line, so they are not created until the entire line finishes. End the line declaring the first two vars before declaring the third one.

```
var start_date = $("#table_date_start").val();
var end_date = $("#table_date_end").val();
```

Comment: Now I'm intrigued as to why are they available outside :)

Comment: Appears to be a browser specific problem as comma separated variables work fine in chrome, but not in IEdge: https://jsfiddle.net/5j7kro38/1/

Comment: I would imagine it's based on the individual browser's implementation of Javascript then.

Comment: @Adelin, I'm sorry for the confusion. Of course, they don't work as the global variables, but if I declare the same variables outside the function, they would give the desired output.